# Microsoft Report Builder - Static portion alongside tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I need to be able to create a landscape report where 3/4 of the page includes a tablix that may span multiple pages. The last 1/4 of the page will contain a full height static portion that will repeat on every page.
I've tried using a nested tablix but if I try to make the column repeat on every page, I get an error stating that the column cannot be set to repeat. I found a packing list from Amazon that matches the desired effect perfectly but have absolutely no idea how to format this.

[Packing Slip](https://alt2.minisoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Amazon_B2B_4X6.png)

Comment: Have you thought of spliting the report into 2 columns.. and using the right column for the static portion? Look for Columns under report properties